# Do pain au chocolats stack?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've thrown 3 pain au chocolats down the well, and spent one on each upgrade. If I were to throw another down, would the effects stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do stack, yes. I stacked a couple of spell and potion countdown reductions so I'm now sitting at 60%.

Once you cannot stack them anymore, the option for that particular power-up will disappear from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've passed 5000% on my power gifts.